# PHP, Regex - how to disallow non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a regex that would allow input including at least one digit and at least one letter (no matter if upper or lower case) AND NOTHING ELSE. Here's what I've come up with:

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('/(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)([^\W])/i',$code)) {
    echo "=)";
    } else {
    echo "=(";
    }
?>
```

While it gives false if I use only digits or only letters, it gives true if I add $ or # or any other non-alphanumeric sign. Now, I tried putting ^\W into class brackets with both a-z and 0-9, tried to use something like ?=.*[^\W] or ?>! but I just can't get it work. Typing in non-alphanums still results in true. Halp meeee

Comment: What's with "and nothing else"? Is "any input is good if it contains one digit and one letter" what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use anchors so that it matches against the entire string.

```
^(?=.*[a-z]+)(?=.*[0-9]+)(\w+)$
```

Comment: Your regex will never match because the lookaheads require two characters while the expression will only match one. Also, `[^\W]` is the same as `\w`, so just use that instead. Here's a working example: http://regex101.com/r/fP6rJ1 - other than that you're kind of correct about the anchors.

Comment: Anchors....now it seems so obvious. Thank you very much my friend, it's all working now!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using php, why even use regex at all.  You can use `ctype_alnum()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php